# how to set system properties by using -D when running Scalatest in a Maven project

Tags: scala, maven, scalatest

I am new to Scala and Maven, we are starting to use Scalatest to do pre deployment tests for a Java project. We are using maven-scala-plugin to run the tests, and we want to read some parameters (properties) off the command line to run the test, for example:

```
mvn test -Dparam1=value1 -Dparam2=value
```

however the problem is that when we use `System.getProperty("param1")` in tests it gives back `null`, which should be `value1`.

Any advices will be appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect this is because maven forks the process and creates a new JVM to run the tests in. You can disable forking by running it like `mvn -DforkMode=never`.

Answer (score -1):

You can just use the environment variables as

`System.getProperty("param1")` where ever you want to use the system environment, you must pass the value of param1 as `-Dparam1=abc` in mvn command, else it will throw some nullexception in your code.